# Solver Glitch? Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, constraints, solver

I am working on an optimization problem using solver and every time I open the solver Parameters, it adds additional constraints that I did not add myself.

For example.  I have three constraints entered that I want to use for this problem.

```
$H$14 <= $H$13
$K$14 <= $K$13
$N$14 <= $N$13
```

When I save this and close solver and run it it works perfectly.  Then when I re-open solver parameters by clicking on the solver button under the Data tab in excel to view the existing constraints, there are over 20 constraints that make no sense added to the constraints.  These added constraints then make the solver answer wrong.

The additional constraints change each time I open solver.  Here are an example of a few of them.

```
$K$14 <= $R$33
$K$14 <= $R$33
$K$14 <= $R$33
$K$14 <= $R$33
$K$14 <= $R$33
$H$14 <= $O$33
$H$14 <= $O$33
$H$14 <= $O$33
$H$14 <= $O$33
$P$21 <= $W$40
$P$21 <= $W$40
$P$21 <= $W$40
$P$21 <= $W$40
```

It adds multiple repeats of each added constraint, and all of these cells are empty, so it completely ruins my solver solution.  I am developing this program for a project and I need it to not mess up every time my professor opens the constraints to observe what I did.  I have tried opening the file on separate computers and it does the same thing.  Has anyone else ever encounter this?  Am I doing something wrong that is resulting in these additional constraints being made?  Any helps appreciated.  I can send the file if someone wants to take a look at it themselves.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you move them to be 3 contiguous ie H14:J14 <= H15:J15 which means it is only 1 listed...

Comment: @SolarMike I mean I could, it would require me completely restructuring the layout of the model though.  The three constraints are not all next to each other.  And how would that solve the issue of solver just adding random constraints every time I open it?

Comment: Well, I spend a **lot** of time using the solver, and I tend to arrange the constraints so that they are in blocks... Mind you, I have never seen it do this... Which solver engine are you using? Linear or Non or evolutionary? Is excel up to date? What about the system? PC or Mac? If you have not tried it on a Mac give it a go.... I have found the solver to be possibly more stable...

Comment: @SolarMike I am on Mac.  And the fact that solver usually is unstable on macs operating system was my first though as well.  I switch over to windows using parallel and Im still encountering the problem (usually this solves any issues im experiencing).  Im worried that the file is somehow corrupted, and I really do not have time to rebuild the whole thing from scratch.  I can try updating excel, but Im fairly sure Im on the most up to date version.  Ill try that now and get back to you.  Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are reading, I made the point that "if you have not tried it on a Mac then give it a go as I find it possibly more stable" ... NOT less stable... Parallels just add another layer...  Oh, another thing to try is removing the solver, quit excel, restart, run excel, quit then run excel and re-install the solver...

Comment: @SolarMike My excel is up-to-date.  And I am using GRG Nonlinear as the solving method.  Like I said, it runs perfectly fine if I do not re-open solver after setting the initial constraints.  But the moment I click the Solver button it pops up showing an additional 20+ constraints that are completely random... Its driving me crazy.

Comment: @SolarMike sorry for mis-reading your original message.  I was initially working with it on the mac operating system and thats when I first encountered the problem.  After failing to find a solution on there I switched to windows (this has worked for me in the past) and the problem still exists.

Comment: @SolarMike I will attempt to uninstall solver now and follow the steps you described.  Thanks

Comment: The other thing is to only have the one workbook open which is using the solver, multiple workbooks being open can also confuse it...

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it helps, but it's worth a shot...

I had similar issues with my Solver (it was remembering my previous setup and constraints). You will notice that Excel remembers your Solver settings (scenarios) by saving them as hidden Names. First, you need to run a VBA code to unhide all Names:

```
Sub UnhideNames()
    Dim nme As Excel.Name

    For Each nme In Excel.Names
        nme.Visible = True
    Next nme
End Sub
```

After you run it, come back to Formulas > "Name Manager" and you should notice a set of Solver-specific ranges that you can manually delete. Hopefully this will solve your issues... fingers crossed!